# HTTP Error 500.0 _Internal Server Error " An unkownn FastCGI Server Error"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I just installed phpMyAdmin into root directory of IIS10 **ineptpub > wwwroot** in my desktop.
[image]

However when I type `localhost/phpMyAdmin/index.php`, I get Error

```
500.0- Internal Server Error " An unknow
FastCGI error occured.
```

I did install phpMyAdmin in my desktop with same settings and runs well but not in the lap top.

Comment: So is there any configuration difference between systems? have you checked error logs of server?

Comment: Non there is o difference between the two.  I ended up uninstalling pho 7.2 and installed  version 8.0 ,  now I get  the following:

Comment: PhpMyAdmin Error- the Extension mysqli is missing